# Can we Scrape & download audios taken from the news website using python code?

Tags: python, audio, web-scraping

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/pg/state.counsellor/videos/ref=page_internal")

folder = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Web 
Scraping\Facebook_Page\All_Videos" + "\\"

#element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('uiGd _51mz')
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ay5')
element1 = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
list = []
for a in element1:
    list.append(a.get_attribute('href'))


final_list = [] 
for num in list: 
    if num not in final_list: 
        final_list.append(num) 

del final_list[-1]

request.urlretrieve(final_list[1],'file.mp4')    
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/state.president/videos/301269537439407/'
request.urlretrieve('https://www.facebook.com/state.counsellor/videos/301269537439407/','file4.mp4')
```

To download audios & videos from from the news website(https://www.bbc.com/news/video_and_audio/headlines) or facebook website using python

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and how it didn't work for you

Comment: Scraping websites, especially scraping them for videos and audios, can be *very* 
complex which is confirmed by python tutor